# Intune wrapping tool not able to sign the ipa file

Tags: ipa, intune

I am trying to wrap my .ipa file using intune wrapping tool and getting below error. Can someone please help.

Warning: Unable to verify system settings for certificate revocation checks. If you would like to enforce certificate revocation checks, run the following commands - 'defaults write com.apple.security.revocation CRLStyle BestAttempt' and 'defaults write com.apple.security.revocation OCSPStyle BestAttempt'

Here is the complete log.

```
Application packaging in progress...
Version of MACOSX is 10.15.7
Version of XCode installed is Xcode 12.4
Build version 12D4e

Parsing provisioning profile...
Parsing main app provisioning profile...
Parsing extension provisioning profiles...
Checking that main provisioning profile has not expired...
Checking that extension provisioning profiles have not expired...
Checking if signing certificate is valid...
Provided certificate name length matches that of SHA1 hash.
Number of certificates returned by query: 4
Checking certificate at index: 0
Getting certificate common name.
Computing SHA-1 fingerprint of current certificate.
Computing SHA-1 fingerprint of provided certificate.
Checking certificate at index: 1
Getting certificate common name.
Computing SHA-1 fingerprint of current certificate.
Computing SHA-1 fingerprint of provided certificate.
Possible fingerprint match found. Checking if certificate is contained in provisioning profile...
Computing SHA-256 fingerprint of certificate.
Checking if SHA-256 hash exists in provisioning profile.
Certificate was found in the provisioning profile.
Checking if certificate issuer is Apple.
Checking if signing certificate is found in each extension profile...
Creating temporary directories...
Input Parameters
 Path to input application:     /Users/madansandiri/Downloads/XX-5.2.7-unsigned.ipa
 Path to output application:    /Users/madansandiri/Downloads/XX-wrapped.ipa
 Provisioning profile:          /Users/madansandiri/Downloads/Intune_Test.mobileprovision
 Certificate:       B7 XX XX XA X1 XX XB 2F XX 3C 1A XX 7C BD XX XX XX 57 AD FB
Packager Version: 14.3.5, Packager Build: 2104.5, App Build: 5, Concatenated Build: 2123.8.5
The app's Frameworks directory could not be signed. This may be because it contains files whose format was unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable.
Cause of the error to be provided for investigation:Error Domain=IntuneAppPackager Code=1 "/usr/bin/codesign exited with an error." UserInfo={Error Description=SignFrameworksError, NSLocalizedDescription=/usr/bin/codesign exited with an error.}
```

Comment: Does your ipa contains any swift libraries (in XX.app/Frameworks/libswift*)? If yes, check if your project has "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" option set to YES. Try by changing it to NO.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open keychain on your mac system.
2. Search for iOS distribution certificate in tab 'certificates' in the keychain and expand the certificate.
3. Select the private key and do the right-click on it --> Click on option 'Get info'
4. Go to 'Access Control' tab.
5. Select 'Allow all applications to access this item'.
6. Enter the mac login or system admin password and click on the allow to save the changes.
7. Open terminal on mac system with root access and Execute following two commands in given order.

> defaults write com.apple.security.revocation CRLStyle BestAttempt

> defaults write com.apple.security.revocation OCSPStyle BestAttempt

8. Re-run wrapping steps to get successful wrapping instance of ios app.

#If steps given above helped you in order to resolve your issue, then give thumbs-up to this contribution.